# large data transformation in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a large data set (ten 12gb csv files)  that have 25 columns and would want to transform it to a dataset with 6 columns. the first 3 columns remains the same whereas the 4th one would be the variable names and the rest contains data. Below is my input:

```
#RIC    Date[L] Time[L] Type    L1-BidPrice L1-BidSize  L1-AskPrice L1-AskSize  L2-BidPrice L2-BidSize  L2-AskPrice L2-AskSize  L3-BidPrice L3-BidSize  L3-AskPrice L3-AskSize  L4-BidPrice L4-BidSize  L4-AskPrice L4-AskSize  L5-BidPrice L5-BidSize  L5-AskPrice L5-AskSize
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 32000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 44000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 32000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 Market Depth    5.29    50000   5.3 38000   5.28    50000   5.31    50000   5.27    50000   5.32    50000   5.26    50000   5.33    50000           5.34    50000
```

and I would transform it to:

```
#RIC    Date[L] Time[L] level   Bid_price   bid_volume  Ask_price   Ask_volume
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 L1  5.29    50000   5.3 50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 L2  5.28    50000   5.31    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L3  5.27    50000   5.32    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L4  5.26    50000   5.33    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L5              
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L1  5.29    50000   5.3 50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L2  5.28    44000   5.31    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L3  5.27    48000   5.32    50000
HOU.ALP 20150901    30:12.1 L4  5.26    50000   5.33    50000
```

Here is my attempt with the coding. I think I would have to use dictionary to write to a csv file

```
def depth_data_transformation(input_file_list, output_file):

for file in input_file_list:
    file_to_open = '%s.csv' %file
    with open(file_to_open) as f, open(output_file, "w") as out:
        next(f) # skip header
        cols = ["#RIC", "Date[L]", "Time[L]", "level", "Bid_price", "bid_volume", "Ask_price", "Ask_volume"]
        wr = csv.writer(out)
        wr.writerow(cols)
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            # get all but first three cols
            it = row[4:]
            # zip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue="") -> group into 4's, add empty string for missing values
            for ind, t in enumerate(izip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue=""), 1):
               # first 3 cols, level and group all in one row/list.
                wr.writerow(row[:3]+ ["l{}".format(ind)] + list(t))
```

Comment: "Here is my attempt with the coding" : I think the snippet of your code is not complete

Comment: @MMF just updated now

Comment: What is `depth_transformed`? If it is a writer object that is writing to a new file then your code does what you want so what is the issue?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham depth_transformed is the csv writer which I use to write to a csv file. The issue is I don't know how to iterate from column 5 to 25 and write them to different lines (row) where first line contain level 1 bid and ask, and second line contains level 2 bid and ask etc

Comment: Ah ok, i see what you want now. Where is the depth coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham do you mean the database? TRTH. or do you mean the input files? they are the files in input_file_list

Comment: Honestly, when you start getting to file sizes this large, why not use PySpark?

Comment: @duckman, it is ok, I had a typo in when I recreated the file locally.

Comment: @duckman, are you sure your expected output is correct? First of you have 24 columns not 25 and there are 5 levels for each to how is it possible you expect the output you do? You also have 8 columns in your expected output where you say you want 6

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry for the confusion. your solution seems to work as the output looks like what I want. The output in the question is just a rough idea of the format, the values might be wrong. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the levels, i.e `L1-BidPrice L1-BidSize  L1-AskPrice L1-AskSize` and write each to a new row :

```
import csv  
from itertools import zip_longest # izip_longest python2


with open("infile.csv") as f, open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    next(f) # skip header
    cols = ["#RIC", "Date[L]", "Time[L]", "level", "Bid_price", "bid_volume", "Ask_price", "Ask_volume"]
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    wr.writerow(cols)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        # get all but first three cols.
        it = row[4:]
        # zip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue="") -> group into 4's, add empty string for missing values
        for ind, t in enumerate(zip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue=""), 1):
           # first 3 cols, level and group all in one row/list.
            wr.writerow(row[:3]+ ["l{}".format(ind)] + list(t))
```

Which would give you:

```
#RIC,Date[L],Time[L],level,Bid_price,bid_volume,Ask_price,Ask_volume
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l1,5.29,50000,5.3,32000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l2,5.28,50000,5.31,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l3,5.27,50000,5.32,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l4,5.26,50000,5.33,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l5,5.34,50000,,
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l1,5.29,50000,5.3,44000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l2,5.28,50000,5.31,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l3,5.27,50000,5.32,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l4,5.26,50000,5.33,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:10.8,l5,5.34,50000,,
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l1,5.29,50000,5.3,32000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l2,5.28,50000,5.31,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l3,5.27,50000,5.32,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l4,5.26,50000,5.33,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l5,5.34,50000,,
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l1,5.29,50000,5.3,38000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l2,5.28,50000,5.31,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l3,5.27,50000,5.32,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l4,5.26,50000,5.33,50000
HOU.ALP,20150901,30:12.1,l5,5.34,50000,,
```

In `for ind, t in enumerate(zip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue=""), 1)`, *`enumerate`* with a start index of 1 is keeping track of which *group/level* we are at.

*`zip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue="")`* groups the cols into sections i.e `L1-BidPrice,L1-BidSize,L1-AskPrice,L1-AskSize`, `L2-BidPrice,L2-BidSize,L2-AskPrice,L2-AskSize` etc.. all the way to `Ln-..`

You have `HOU.ALP 20150901    30:10.8 L1  5.29    50000   5.3 50000` in your expected output but 32000 is the value in your input for `L1-AskSize`, each row has 5 levels and you also have 8 columns so I presume your expected output is wrong.

Comment: Can I just copy and paste this? do I add # izip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue="") -> group into 4's, add empty string fotr missing values?

Comment: @duckman, that is just a comment to explain what is happening.

Comment: for ind, t in enumerate(izip_longest(*[iter(it)] * 4, fillvalue=""), 1):
           # first 3 cols, level and group all in one row/list.
            wr.writerow(row[:3]+ ["l{}".format(ind)] + list(t))

Comment: What the above does? sorry I pressed Enter and it was just posted

Comment: No worries, I will add a bit more explanation when I am back on my notebook.

Comment: While you are at this, Could you please have a quick look at my code below. It is similar to yours except I modified so that it is a function which reads multiple files and write to 1 output file.

Comment: it was too long for a comment. Please see the original post above

Comment: You keep overwriting in the loop, open the file you are writing to once before the for loop or open with a for append as opposed to w.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126041/discussion-between-duckman-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: you forgot to explain what the code (see comment above) does? :-(

Comment: the output file has an empty line between lines. Do you know how to get rid of the empty lines?